# Реализация настроек сайта в Yii2 Advanced

Tags: yii2

Доброго времени суток. 
Возник вопрос по реализации настроек сайта в Yii2. Мы хотим задать полям, например:

- Имя сайта
- Описание сайта
- Путь к лого сайта
- API-ключ сервиса антиспама

*...etc*

Я почитал документацию, и насколько я понял, лучше подобные конфигурации в Yii2 Advanced хранить в `common/main-local.php`.

Поэтому, есть 2 вопроса:

1. Правильно ли будет хранить подобные настройки в `common/main-local.php`?
2. Если да, как можно к ним обратиться с контроллера/модели/вида?

---

UPD:

Почитал ещё информацию на нескольких ресурсах. Судя по всему, параметры лучше хранить: `common/config/params.php` и получить через `Yii::$app->params`.
Собственно, это верный вариант?

Comment: все верно, все настройки необходимо хранить в params.php

Answer (score 1):

Тут больше вопрос в том, как часто они будут меняться.
Вариантов много. Если настройки задаются единожды, да, можно через params для глобальных, или через настройки компонента\модуля для конкретной сущности. 
Например у Вас есть модуль платежной системы с  параметрами:

```
'payment' => [
            'class' => 'payment\Module',
            'components' => [
                'paymentApi' => [
                    'class' => '\payment\api\PaymentApi',
                    'type' => 'TEST',
                    'token' => 'sdvdsfvdfsv23142',

                ],
            ],
        ],
```

И эти данные попадут в публичные свойства PaymentApi
Их также можно переопределять локальным конфигом common/main-local.php 
Если настройки часто меняются, можно хранить их в бд. 
Т.е. сделать модуль settings с моделькой настройки settings('name',  'value') и апи к этому, чтобы можно было в любой части приложения написать:

```
Yii::$app->getModule('settings')->api->get('name', $default)
```